# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.handleEmail')

Tags: javascript, react-native

Working on a login Screen. When I run the app for the first time by the command `npx react-native run-android` it works fine but when I reload it it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')

This error is located at:
    in Login (at App.js:6)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default function Login(){
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
     }
     handleEmail = (text) => {
        this.setState({ email: text })
     }
     handlePassword = (text) => {
        this.setState({ password: text })
     }
     login = (email, pass) => {
        alert('email: ' + email + ' password: ' + pass)
     }
    return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.container1}>
            <Text style = {styles.titleText}>This is my title</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.titleSlogan}>This is my text</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.container2}>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Email"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>
        
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Password"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>
        
        <TouchableOpacity
           style = {styles.submitButton}
           onPress = {
              () => this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
           }>
           <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
     </View>
    )
}
```

Kindly, someone guide me what can I do as I am in the beginning stage and don't know the technicalities.

Comment: There are two ways to write components in React. 'Class' components use `this.state` and `this.setState`. 'Function' components use hooks like `useState`. In your example you're kind of mixing the syntax of both together, which is why it doesn't work. Your syntax is closer to a class component. I suggest you Google "react class Vs function component" and look at some simple examples to understand the difference. It's useful to know both ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comment on the original post that suggests you look into class vs function components. The commenter is correct that your original code is *closer* to a class component. But, I think there's a lot of value in learning how function components work, since it seems like that's the direction React is heading in.

```
export default function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('')

     const handleEmail = (text) => {
        setEmail(text)
     }
     const handlePassword = (text) => {
        setPassword(text)
     }
     const login = (email, pass) => {
        alert('email: ' + email + ' password: ' + pass)
     }
    return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.container1}>
            <Text style = {styles.titleText}>IbexCoin</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.titleSlogan}>The Future CryptoCurrency</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.container2}>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Email"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {handleEmail}/>
        
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
           placeholder = "Password"
           placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {handlePassword}/>
        
        <TouchableOpacity
           style = {styles.submitButton}
           onPress = {
              () => login(email, password)
           }>
           <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
     </View>
    )
}
```

Instead of having one state (`this.state`), the email and password are stored in separate variables using the `useState` hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

The handleEmail, handlePassword, login, etc functions are now declared inline as `const` instead of being properties on a class.

`return()` at the end stays the same -- if this were a class component, you would've wanted a `render()` function that returned all of that stuff.

All references to `this` are removed in a function component.

There's more refactoring that could be done, but this should get you started and on your way learning about state in function components.